# Limit CMake include_directories() scope?

Tags: compilation, cmake

So here's my problem:

I like to (for whatever reason, am willing to change if there's a better way) split my code up into a directory tree structure and put the header files in the same directory as the corresponding source file. This works fine, except for when I need to add a directory. When I add a new directory, I call `include_directories()` with the new directory as the argument.

Calling `include_directories` causes the compiler to include the directory for every file (i.e. `-I NEW_DIRECTORY`) , regardless of whether or not the file actually depends on a header file in that directory. This triggers a re-build of the entire code, which is very undesirable.

Is there a better way? I'd really like to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html).

`include_directories` is based on directory properties, which means every target in the same folder (or any subfolder) of the `CMakeLists.txt` that calls `include_directories`, will get the respective include directory added.

`target_include_directories` on the other hand is based on target properties, which means you have to call it again for every target (that is, for every library or executable in your project). The advantage is that this is usually a more natural way of specifying those dependencies. Also, directories specified as `PUBLIC` will automatically be pulled in by dependent targets, a feature that is not available with `include_directories`.

Comment: how to use target_include_directories() with add_subdirectory()?